# How to vertically align verbatim text and image in two columns to the top in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment, verbatim, includegraphics

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{verbatim}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      \end{verbatim}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{320px-Herald_of_Free_Enterprise.jpg}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Link to the image used in the above code:**

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Herald_of_Free_Enterprise.jpg/320px-Herald_of_Free_Enterprise.jpg

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:**

The top of the verbatim text and the top of the image are not aligned even after using `T` option for `columns`. How can I vertically align them to the top?

Answer (score 1):

I'd set the `verbatim` content in a box (via `lrbox`) before using it (via `\usebox`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{verbatim}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      \end{verbatim}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\newsavebox{\verbbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \usebox{\verbbox}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that the difference in horizontal alignment between the two `Lorem ipsum dolor sit` phrases stems from the indentation within the `verbatim` environment.